# In REXML XPATH match function, what do multiple namespaces do in the namespace mapping?

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, rexml

I'm trying to understand exactly what line 785 does here:

https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml/blob/15fb4789f8cd119fdbd722d58c659129d23a256d/lib/onelogin/ruby-saml/response.rb#L777

however I can find no clear explanation of this in the docs e.g. here:

https://contest-server.cs.uchicago.edu/ref/ruby_1_9_3_stdlib/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/REXML/XPath.html#method-c-match

I.e. I can understand what targeting a single namespace ("ps") does, but what does the addition of the second namespace ("d") do?

Edit: follow up clarification:  would a document starting with this be successfully parsed, given that the 'protocol' namespace is lower-case in the document but upper case in the code?

```
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Version="2.0" >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response being queried via XPath uses two different namespaces,

- The namespace bound to the `p` namespace prefix is for [SAML
  Core](https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-metadata-2.0-os.pdf) (`urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol`).
- The namespace bound to `ds` is for [XML Signature](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core2/)
  (`http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#`).

and both are declared to the XPath processor via the argument to `REXML::XPath.match` on the cited line in the code:

```
      { "p" => PROTOCOL, "ds" => DSIG },
```

---

### Update per question update

The ***namespace prefix*** (`p`) is arbitrary and need not match the one used in the document.  The ***namespace*** (`urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol`) is what's important and must match the one used in the document.  Both are case-sensitive.

Comment: thanks!  i made an edit to the question, with a clarification, this is the core matter i was trying to resolve.